# Single form that spans across tabs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, haml, simple-form

I want to span a form across tabs so a single submit button submits edits no matter which tab was edited.  Here is what I've tried that isn't working.  I'm using Rails 4, haml, simple_form, and Bootstrap 3.

```
%ul.nav.nav-tabs
  %li.active
  %a{"data-toggle" => "tab", href: "#tab_1"} Tab 1
  %li
  %a{"data-toggle" => "tab", href: "#tab_2"} Tab 2
.tab-content
  =simple_form_for @account do |f|
    #tab_1.tab-pane.active
    =f.input :account_number
    =f.input :name
    #tab_2.tab-pane
    =f.input :account_datails_1
    =f.input :account_deatils_2
    .form-actions
      = f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary'
      = link_to 'Cancel', accounts_path, :class => 'btn'
```

I know I can place a separate form on each tab, but I want to separate out details on other tabs with a single submit.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've run into this before and all I had to do was this (granted this might not be ideal practice but did work for me):

```
=simple_form_for @account do |f|
  %ul.nav.nav-tabs
    %li.active
    %a{"data-toggle" => "tab", href: "#tab_1"} Tab 1
    %li
    %a{"data-toggle" => "tab", href: "#tab_2"} Tab 2
  .tab_content  
    #tab_1.tab-pane.in.active
    =f.input :account_number
    =f.input :name
    #tab_2.tab-pane
    =f.input :account_datails_1
    =f.input :account_deatils_2
  .form-actions
    = f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary'
    = link_to 'Cancel', accounts_path, :class => 'btn'
```

In essence, just move the '= simple_form' expression above the .tab_content

Comment: Thanks Craig, but dang it, that didn't help.  I think you are on the right track, something with nesting.

Comment: No problem ... it should just be ordering of elements (i.e., nesting). I double-checked my HAML code where this was an issue and I was able to place the simple_form_for stuff outside my tabs but might've done it wrong in the answer above (maybe try swapping the .tab_content and the = simple_form_for?)

Comment: I got it working and updated your answer to reflex the correct order.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sweet ... Glad it's sorted!